# Android: How to stop / start loading process for Glide like Android Volley?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm following this excellent article: [here](http://optimizationtricks.blogspot.fr/2014/01/tricks-to-boost-performance-of-list-view.html); I use Glide library to load all remote images. So I would like to know how can I stop and start the **Glide** loading process like Google Volley in this example:

```
@Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView listView, int scrollState) {
                // Pause disk cache access to ensure smoother scrolling
                if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                        imageLoader.stopProcessingQueue();
                } else {
                        imageLoader.startProcessingQueue();
                }
        }
```

Comment: Hi...did you find anything on this?

Comment: Hi Aditi! No, I didn't find something perfect.